# Struts 2 jquery plugin sj:select and jquery.select2

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-select2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

We have used struts 2 jquery plugin. We have changed all selects to `jquery select2`.

```xml
$('select:visible:not').select2()
```

The are lots of `sj:selects` selects which reload via ajax like:

```xml
    <s:select id="areaCode" name="areaCode" list="areas" listKey="top"
        listValue="areaName" headerKey=""
        headerValue="Select It"/>

    <sj:select id="realodedBranches" name="openerBranchNo"
        list="realodedBranches" href="%{reloadbranch}" listKey="branchCode"
        listValue="branchName" reloadTopics="reloadBranches"/>
```

Every thing work fine, expect when the event returns only one result row, and the select box will have only one option. At this state the select 2 will not allow user to select this option!

If I change the result to return more that one result, it work fine.

I see this problem only when I reload selects, I don't know why this happens.

I have made a simple test with jquery select 2 only and it works fine and the added option is selectable:

```xml
<select id="mainSelect">
</select>    

<button id="clickMe">Click Me </button>


$('select').select2();

$('#clickMe').click(function(){
     $('#mainSelect')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value","val1")
         .text("text1"));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the added option is one the select2 automaticly added the `aria-selected="true"` to first option. This prevent it to be selected.

It seems to be be a bug https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3242

To solve it you can set the `sj:select` , `emptyOption="true"` property, this is some how a work around but will add an empty option and select 2 mark this empty option as `selected`

Still looking for better approach !

Comment: `aria-selected="true"` means that it is already selected. You need to update select2 after inserting new values.

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks, the select 2 updates when the associated select box option changes and you can see the updated options, but it make it selected, by mistake. PS: If you mean calling the `trigger('change')`, I did and it but no luck :(

Comment: Calling `.select2()` again: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19899983/1700321 or something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16480910/1700321.